# Is Spring 5 compatible with Hibernate 6.1?

Tags: spring, hibernate

**The Problem**

We currently have a Spring MVC application (non-spring-boot) based on Spring 5 and Hibernate 5. We have to migrate the app to Hibernate 6.1.

During testing we are encountering exceptions once upgraded to Hibernate 6.1. The root cause exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder
```

Is Spring 5 compatible with Hibernate 6.1? I checked the Spring.io website but could not find any compatibility information for spring-orm.

**What I Expected**

I expected the application to work with Hibernate 6.1 upgrade.

**Environment**

- Spring MVC 5.3.21 (non-spring-boot)
- Hibernate 6.1.0
- Tomcat 9.0.64
- Java 13
- Ubuntu 20

**Research Performed**

I checked the spring.io website and reference manual. I could not find compatibility information for spring-orm and Hibernate 6.1

**How to Reproduce**

Deploy a Spring MVC web app (non-spring-boot) that uses Spring 5.3.21 and Hibernate 6.1

Comment: No. Because Hibernate 6 is a JakartaEE implementation and not a JavaEE implementation it isn't supported.

Comment: Spring 5.6 is internally using old Hibernate 5.x references, for example in org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/HibernateTemplate.java you can find imports of org.hibernate.Criteria and org.hibernate.criterion, which were both removed in Hibernate 6.